# encoding image into text... resulting: smaller 'raw' text

Tags: encoding

i'm trying to encode an image into text and i've tried base64' and the result is a LARGE 'raw' text.

is there any other algorithm (?) which will give me a smaller 'raw' text!?

tnx in advance

Comment: What kind of image ?   What needs to happen to the text after its converted back to an image ?  What are the constraints on "text"?

Comment: you get that encoding it this way would increase the size of the data, right? just taking the HEX of the original image is more than sufficient, and doesn't introduce additional cost in storage.

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) (for example used by the btoa utility) is more efficient then Base64 and uuencode.